# How do I run Valgrind on a program that needs superuser permission?

Tags: c, valgrind, sudo

I'm writing a packet sniffer in C (using libpcap) and I can't use Valgrind to find memory leaks in my program as it must be run with superuser permissions, because, without this, I can't even open the network interface for capture.

When I try to run Valgrind with `sudo`, I got this:

```
$ valgrind sudo ./[exec]
==5211== 
==5211== Warning: Can't execute setuid/setgid/setcap executable: /usr/bin/sudo
==5211== Possible workaround: remove --trace-children=yes, if in effect
==5211== 
valgrind: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

So I tried to run as superuser (`sudo su`) and got this:

```
# valgrind ./[exec]
valgrind: ./bin/TP2: Permission denied
```

As well as:

```
$ sudo valgrind ./[exec]
valgrind: ./bin/TP2: Permission denied
```

I've searched all the Internet to find an answer for that.

In short, I need to find memory leaks in my packet sniffer and it must be run with admin permissions. Can someone help me with that or, at least, recommend me another memory checker, please?

Comment: Why are you using mixed notations: you run `./[exec]` and yet get `./bin/TP2` in the error messages.  You'd do better to be self-consistent, such as using `./TP2` everywhere.

Comment: Is the program stored on a file system mounted with `nosuid` option?  Does the program have an `x` bit set on its permissions?  Even root needs an `x` bit to run a program.  What are the permissions on the directory?  Can you run `./[exec]` as yourself, getting an appropriate EPERM (no permission, or 'operation not permitted') error?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think Valgrind is complaining about the `suid` for the program, but for `sudo`. `sudo` would usually be inside the bin and the filesystem for that won't have `nosuid`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: You're probably right. I'm trying to get more information from the OP about permissions, because it is not clear why the Valgrind can't execute `./bin/TP2` (according to the error messages) or `./[exec]` (according to the command line supposedly generating the messages referring to `./bin/TP2`).  Mostly, the superuser can execute programs — so seeing permission denied is a little unexpected.  The question is "what's peculiar about the setup such that the program can't be run".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, `./[exec]` seems a bit funny, since it would only match files `e`, `x` and `c` not `/bin/TP2`. I think only OP can clarify

Comment: [exec] is probable just a placeholder name, not a regular expression.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah yes, that was a mistake on my copy & paste. Thanks! 
Actually "[exec]" is just a notation for a executable (in this case, /bin/TP2).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right! It was a problem with permissions because the program were placed on a NTFS volume. When I moved it to a Ex4, finally I could set correct permissions for the program run with Valgrind as superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I had no clue that the problem were because the volume which my executable is placed on is a NTFS partition. First I moved the file to a random folder on a Ex4 partition, and so, I had changed permissions on my executable with `chmod`.

Now I can run Valgrind on my program when logged as root.